# Add OnClick Event to Html.RadioButton

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

What I want to do is to call a JavaScript routine when the user clicks on a radiobutton.  I've some fields to enable/disable when this happens.  However, when I enter

```
 <%=Html.RadioButton("obp17", "57", ViewData.Eval("obpValue17").ToString().Equals("57"), new {@onclick = "Yes()"})%>
```

I'm getting a **"type or with" expected error** when trying to add the onlick event.  This should be easy, but none of samples I've found seem to work.  The leading "@" is common in all the examples I've found, but something else seems to be missing.

And yes I know the way of checking for "true" is overkill, but it is created with a special purpose code generator, so it wasn't any extra work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `Yes()` function correctly defined in your code ? Replace `Yes()` to the javascript `alert()` function ; if that works, then the line of code you posted is OK.

Also, please post `Yes()` function here, and I think there may be some error there.

Comment: I replaced Yes() with alert and had the same problem

Answer (score 6):

Pardon me for causing anyone problems.  My problem was ultimately caused by delete the first line of the ASCX file that inherits "System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl"  Once I put that in, all the problems went away.

The line of code that worked was

```
 <%= Html.TextBox("obpt9",ViewData.Eval("obpt9"), new { onclick = "alert('hi')" })%>
```

Different line than sample, but they are all the same.

Again, sorry for causing anyone confusion.

tom

Answer (score 2):

Is the page language VB or C#?  If it's VB your syntax is wrong for creating the anonymous typed html attributes.  See this [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx) on how to create an object with an anonymous type in VB.

```
 <%=Html.RadioButton("obp17",
                     "57",
                     ViewData.Eval("obpValue17").ToString().Equals("57"),
                     New With { .onclick = "Yes()" } ) %>
```

Or change the page language to C#, if that's more appropriate.

Also, note that you could (arguably should) simply give the radio button a class, then add all the handlers at one time with jQuery.  Usually you want to keep your javascript separate from your mark up.

```
 <%=Html.RadioButton("obp17",
                     "57",
                     ViewData.Eval("obpValue17").ToString().Equals("57"),
                     New With { .class = "heinz" } ) %>

 <script type="text/javascript>
     $('.heinz').click( function() {
        ... implement the logic of Yes() here ...
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: what makes you think he is using vb, with the "new" keywoard, it looks like he is using c#.

Comment: Because the error looks like a compiler error, not a browser error, and, if so, indicates that it is expecting class identifier or the With keyword for anonymous types. I wouldn't expect this to be the case if the page language is C#.

Comment: expecting VB instead of C# is what popped into my head as well... This answer is likely spot on.

Answer (score 2):

The general structure Looks like the following:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(t => t.ViewModelVariableName,"RadioButtonValue", new {javascriptEvent = "javascriptMethodName"});
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I had to change the 3rd parameter to `new { @onclick = "javascriptMethodName()" }`