# Remove text onclick/onfocus event of @Html.TextArea

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, onclick, html.textbox

I am working on an MVC 3 project.
In my view I have textboxes and Text area which I am calling using @Html.TextBox/TextArea.

Can anyone please tell me, how can I define the onclick or onfocus even of these controls?
I am unable to find a syntax for this.

Comment: I am using Razor engine for my view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **TextBox**

```
@Html.TextBox("ControlName",
                "Some Value",
                  new { onclick = "alert('Razor Engine')" });
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Value, new
                                {
                                    onclick = "alert('Razor Engine')",
                                    @Value = "Some Value"
                                });
```

### **TextArea**

```
@Html.TextArea("ControlName",
                "Some Value",
                  new { onclick = "alert('Razor Engine')" });
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Value, new
                                {
                                    onclick = "alert('Razor Engine')"
                                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below.

```
 <%= Html.TextBox("obpt9",ViewData.Eval("obpt9"), new { onclick = "alert('hi')" })%>
```

You can find more information from below link.
[Add OnClick Event to Html.RadioButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224202/add-onclick-event-to-html-radiobutton)

Comment: use @ instead of <%= that is simple